# Unrespect vs Disrespect

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is it ok to say "do not unrespect me" instead of "do not disrespect me"?

I heard someone say it and it struck me as odd.

Comment: ...but not a [widely-recognized](http://www.onelook.com/?w=unrespect&ls=a) noun. Compare with [disrespect](http://www.onelook.com/?w=disrespect&ls=a).

Comment: Unrespect as a verb sounds to me like you once respected someone and you are withdrawing your respect for them, especially since as JR points out, as a noun meaning 'disrespect' it's long since obsolete. Where was this person from? It may still exist as a regionalism

Comment: "ok to say" is rather nebulous. If the speaker is try to sound peculiar, then of course it is "ok" to say. If the speaker is trying to use formal/accepted/standard English (choose your own adjective), then it's probably best avoided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the person saying "unrespect" is almost certainly confused. The correct term is "disrespect" as in:

"Do not disrespect me."

Answer (score -2):

This answer is based on my (limited) knowledge of American street culture.

"Do not disrespect me" is a dangerous thing to say.  If you say it (or something like it), you should know:

- Why you are worthy of respect.
- Who you are talking to.
- How they are likely to understand what you say.
- What you can do that will make them respect you.
- Whether you are likely to win a fight.

If you do not understand what "Don't dis me" or "Do not disrespect me" means, you should not say it.  Furthermore, you should not say a variation (like "Do not unrespect me") that neither you nor the person you are talking to understands.

"Don't dis me" is slang.  It is used by violent members of America's "street culture".  (It is also used by other people, but this answer focuses on the risk of violence.)  If person A says "Don't dis me" to person B:

- Person B has probably offended person A.
- Person B did something that person A interpreted as being disrespectful.
- Person B might not respect person A.
- Person A demands that person B either show respect for person A, or cease showing a lack of respect for person A.
- If person B does choose to change their behavior toward person A, person B should do so in a way that does not suggest weakness.

The best possible outcome from saying "Don't disrespect me" is that the parties involve clarify their attitudes toward each other, decide on their relative statuses, and move forward peacefully.  (Sometimes fighting is involved in this "clarification" process.)

Another possible outcome is that the demand for respect is rejected with mockery and laughter.

The worst possible outcome from saying "Don't disrespect me" is that a fight ensues, which turns into a grudge or feud.